# Dynamic Height of Rectangle as from text content in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have been trying to achieve to match timeline sidebar height as per the content below header.

But side bar is taking full height, is there any way we can restrict it's height as of middle content. it's in HStackView as below.

```
            //header
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    .overlay(Circle().inset(by: 2).fill(Color.white))
                
                Text("Headline").font(.headline)
            }.padding(0)

            //content
            HStack {
                VStack {
//                    Text("l").padding(.leading,5)
//                    Text("l").padding(.leading,5)
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 20)
                }
                
                Text("Time Line Content Time Line Content Time Line Content Time Line Content fdfgfuysdgfuydsgfgds fgfyusdfyfdsdfsdfgyusdg fydsufidsfy uyfudsfuydsufysdfsdf dfusdtfoisdtftdsoftsdftsydtfsdtfodstfdstf fgdsygfdsgfuygu").font(.caption)
            }
            
            //footer
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.orange)
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    .overlay(Circle().inset(by: 2).fill(Color.white))
                
                Text("Footer").font(.subheadline)
            }.padding(0)
```

Thanks.

[image: TimelineContentView]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understood of your question is that:

1. You have an `HStack` in which the leftmost view is a `Rectangle` and the rightmost view is a `Text`.
2. You want the `Rectangle` to be the same height as the `Text`.

The problem is that the height of the `HStack` is based on the tallest child view which happens to be the `Rectangle` but a `Rectangle` view does not have any intrinsic size like `Text` and will occupy all the space the parent provides, or if you manually apply a frame.
You set a width of 20 but leave height and so it takes the entire height it can get.

This indicates that we need to set the height of the `Rectangle` to be same as the dynamic `Text` but the problem is that we don't know the height upfront.

To solve this:

1. First we need to know the height of the dynamic `Text`.

   - For this we will use [`GeometryReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) and access the height value.
2. The height is in a child view so we need it to notify the parent it's height value.

   - For this we will use [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey)
3. The parent view should update the `Rectangle` when it gets to know the `Text` height

   - A simple `@State` variable will suffice now

---

### Solution:

```
struct ContentLengthPreference: PreferenceKey {
   static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
   
   static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
      value = nextValue()
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State var textHeight: CGFloat = 0 // <-- this
   
   var body: some View {
      HStack {
        Rectangle()
           .frame(width: 20, height: textHeight) // <-- this
        
        Text(String(repeating: "lorem ipsum ", count: 25))
           .overlay(
              GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color
                   .clear
                   .preference(key: ContentLengthPreference.self,
                               value: proxy.size.height) // <-- this
              }
           )
      }
      .onPreferenceChange(ContentLengthPreference.self) { value in // <-- this
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.textHeight = value
        }
      }
   }
}
```

1. Create `ContentLengthPreference` as our `PreferenceKey` implementation
2. on `Text`; Apply `overlay` containing `GeometryReader`
3. `overlay` will have same height as `Text`
4. in `GeometryReader`, `Color.clear` is just a filler invisible view
5. `anchorPreference` modifier allows us to access and store height
6. `onPreferenceChange` modifier on parent `HStack` can catch the value passed by child view
7. parent saves the height to a state property `textHeight`
8. `textHeight` can be applied on `Rectangle` and will update the view when this value updates

<sub>Credits: https://www.wooji-juice.com/blog/stupid-swiftui-tricks-equal-sizes.html</sub>

---

#### Output (including your header + footer views):

[image: Output]

---

### EDIT:

If you have multiple of these in a `List` then you don't need to do anything. Each row will size automatically upto the `Text` height.
It's free!!!

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      List(0..<20) { _ in
        ArticleView()
      }
   }
}

struct ArticleView: View {
   var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
           Circle()
              .fill(Color.blue)
              .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
              .overlay(Circle().inset(by: 2).fill(Color.white))
           
           Text("Headline").font(.headline)
        }
        
        HStack {
           Rectangle().frame(width: 20)
           
           Text(String(repeating: "lorem ipsum ", count: (5...50).randomElement()!))
        }
        
        HStack {
           Circle()
              .fill(Color.orange)
              .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
              .overlay(Circle().inset(by: 2).fill(Color.white))
           
           Text("Footer").font(.subheadline)
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I’m looking for. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: While using in ScrollView with multiple cells, we get fluctuations on screen and in console
"Bound preference ContentLengthPreference tried to update multiple times per frame."

Comment: I don't know why this is too much ???? this will rendering your view many times.

Comment: @khanHussain This seems to cause infinite rendering in a `ScrollView`. However, if you use `List` then you don't need to do anything! You will get your expected UI for free. Check updated answer. Just plain SwiftUI, nothing fancy. If that is still not good enough then please update your question with full details of `ScrollView`.

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes, this is problematic in a `ScrollView` as frame updation starts to go into a loop. I didnt account for this but hopefully the alternate solution might help OP.

Comment: Thanks @staticVoidMan. Using List, its working without extra efforts

Answer (score 2):

A neat option is to combine an overlay and the GeometryReader:

```
HStack {
          Text("some long text........")
               .font(.body)
               .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: proxy.size.height)
            }
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can add max-height like this

```
HStack {
    VStack {
        //                    Text("l").padding(.leading,5)
        //                    Text("l").padding(.leading,5)
        Rectangle().frame(width: 20)
    }
    
    Text("Time Line Content Time Line Content Time Line Content Time Line Content fdfgfuysdgfuydsgfgds fgfyusdfyfdsdfsdfgyusdg fydsufidsfy uyfudsfuydsufysdfsdf dfusdtfoisdtftdsoftsdftsydtfsdtfodstfdstf fgdsygfdsgfuygu").font(.caption)
}.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity) //<---here
```

**Or** Set up your cell view like this

```
struct ContentCellView: View {
    var isLast: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Image(systemName: "message.circle").frame(width: 30)
                if !isLast {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.black).frame(width: 1).padding(.leading, 15.5)
                }
            }
            Text("Time Line Content Time Line Content Time Line Content Time Line Content fdfgfuysdgfuydsgfgds fgfyusdfyfdsdfsdfgyusdg fydsufidsfy uyfudsfuydsufysdfsdf dfusdtfoisdtftdsoftsdftsydtfsdtfodstfdstf fgdsygfdsgfuygu")
        }.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentViewList: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) {
                    ContentCellView(isLast: $0 == 1) // isLast for not showing last line in last cell
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

[image]